# How can I vectorise this Pandas 'row by row' function

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, lambda, vectorization

Here is my python code:

```
def f(row): 
    if row['Unregistered'] ==  "null" and row["Registered"] != "null":
        val = "registered_only"
    elif row['Unregistered'] !=  "null" and row['Registered'] == "null":
        val = "unregistered_only"
    else:
        val = "both"
    return val
```

I have 2 columns: Unregistered and Registered, which occasionally have "null" in them. I have a third column which will state whether there are values in both of these columns, or 1 of them. Making the above function was the easiest way I could manage conceptually, but I know in terms of performance I should not be iterating through each row. However I found it a struggle to convert this function to a lambda function. Furthermore, I don't even know if there is a better way to achieve this with some prebuilt panda functions? So, advice :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use `np.select` and vectorial conditions.